# In a principal ideal domain, gcd(a,b) always exists and can always be expressed as $xa +yb$ with some $x, y /in R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, gcd-and-lcm, principal-ideal-domains

In a principal ideal domain, gcd(a,b) always exists and can always be expressed as $xa +yb$ with some $x, y in R$.

I am quite new to algebra and would be really grateful if someone could show me ow to prove this.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the ideal $I := \{ xa + yb \mid x, y \in R \}$ (why is this an ideal?).

Since it is principal, it is generated by some element, say $r \in I$.

Show that $r$ is a gcd of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: How would I show that?

Comment: Use the definition of gcd.

Comment: @matthijs-bjornlund : Suppose $x$ and $y$ have a common divisor $s$. Show that $s$ must also be a divisor of $r$.

Comment: In this case, since $s$ is a common divisor of both $x $ and $y$, $xa +yb= csa + dsb = s (ca+db)$ where  $x=c.s$ and $y=d.s$. By doing that, we have shown that $s$ is also a divisor of $r$. Once this has been established, is it enough to conclude the above statement?